# Which Azure VM is most suitable for IO intensive service?

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

I have a micro service that’s basically fanning out 1 queue message to a lot of queue messages. 
It is aimed to perform around 30,000 transactions / second.

A transaction can be:

- dequeue queue message (azure storage queue)
- enqueue message (same technology)
- fetch records from azure storage table

In practice I achieve these numbers, however I’m over provisioned as the CPU does not cross the 40% and the network-out bandwidth is only 1/8 of the capacity provided by this VM.

Increasing the concurrency to get higher throughput causes requests to timeout and degrading the performance, so I’m thinking to find a smaller VM, but not sure which one would be optimal for this kind of service.

I don’t mind decreasing the throughput per VM if the ROI is better (when calculating the VM cost) - as I can scale out to compensate.

Comment: You can select one appreciate size which you need [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/sizes). And the size decides the vm for the different purposes.